# paste a file with existing file name in vscode cause them to rename instead of replace existing file

Tags: visual-studio-code

when I copy a file to a folder that a file with same name exist, the new file get renamed  instead of replacing the existing file.

for example if I copy a file `abc.jpg` from one folder into another folder that `abc.jpg` exist. i will end up with two files that the old one is `abc.jpg` and new one is `abc copy.jpg`

it's new feature and wasn't like this before. unfortunately I can't find any configuration to change it, also keywords such as "copy", "file", "replace" is too generic that I can't find a solution for this problem by just googling it.

## Update

if anyone land in here from google, it's a feature that the vscode team need to consider, please [vote/comment in here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/127746)

---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vscode update of september 2022 adds this behaviour.
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_72#_disable-incremental-naming

just change in your settings : `"explorer.incrementalNaming": "disabled"`.

Answer (score 0):

[You get propmted if you want to replace or not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIZut.png)

Comment: I added a gif, please check

Comment: i have the same behaviour, no prompt to replace, always renaming VSC 1.51.1 on linux